# Interaction with sharepoint, severals ways?

Tags: c#, .net, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I've been looking for interaction with Sharepoint from a C# code. Basically, it will be a small application which will add/remove data to a remote sharepoint server.

I've found a lot of things, but essentially two things:

Once we access with a "ClientContext", and after we have a "Site", on which we can found "List", etc...

The other thing I found is to access with "SPSite", and we have "SPList", "SP...", etc..

Am I right? Is this two different to access data? Why this? Which one should I use? On what it depends?

Is there some more possibilites with one of these ways?

Thank you very much :)

Edit: I don't know why, I cannot put a "Hi," at the start of my question, sorry :/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `ClientContext`, `Site`, `Web` and `List` classes are part of SharePoint's [*client* object model](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/gg620623). They allow you to manipulate SharePoint objects from any client machine.

The `SPContext`, `SPSite`, `SPWeb` and `SPList` classes are part of SharePoint's [*server* object model](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms473633.aspx). They allow you to manipulate SharePoint objects from code deployed on the SharePoint servers themselves.

These two technologies are not used in the same way. For instance, query [filtering](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee857094.aspx#SP2010ClientOM_Using_LoadQuery) and [bulking](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.client.clientruntimecontext.executequery.aspx) are important concepts of the client object model, but not of the server object model.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Frédéric Hamidi excellent answer.

This is most likely what you are looking for http://www.bendsoft.com/net-sharepoint-connector/. It connects through the SharePoint API so you can use it for both internal and external development of SharePoint. Foremost you don't need to learn CAML and use SQL instead.

Example

Insert some data

```
public void SharePointConnectionExample1()
{
    using (SharePointConnection connection = new SharePointConnection(@"
                Server=mysharepointserver.com;
                Database=mysite/subsite
                User=spuser;
                Password=******;
                Authentication=Ntlm;
                TimeOut=10;
                StrictMode=True;
                RecursiveMode=RecursiveAll;
                DefaultLimit=1000;
                CacheTimeout=5"))
    {
        connection.Open();
        using (SharePointCommand command = new SharePointCommand("UPDATE `mytable` SET `mycolumn` = 'hello world'", connection))
        {
            command.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
    }
}
```

Or to select list data to a DataTable

```
string query = "SELECT * FROM list";
conn = new SharePointConnection(connectionString);
SharePointDataAdapter adapter = new SharePointDataAdapter(query, conn);

DataTable dt = new DataTable();
adapter.Fill(dt);
```

Or using a helper method to fill a DataGrid

```
string query = "Select * from mylist.viewname";
DataGrid dataGrid = new DataGrid();
dataGrid.DataSource = Camelot.SharePointConnector.Data.Helper.ExecuteDataTable(query, connectionString);
dataGrid.DataBind();
Controls.Add(dataGrid);
```

Take my word for it, this turn SharePoint development into a lot of fun!

Cheers

Comment: I wouldn’t connect to a provided API via an extra 3td party API. It will become harder for you and others to maintain your application.

Comment: JC you might misunderstood the purpose of this, it's an ADO.NET adapter for SharePoint which translates any query you send, a 3rd party api would be something completely different in my opinion. It's good for standardisation and it certainly simplifies the process of working with SharePoint.